# Moving within a list, by giving the possible moves. Prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, maze

So I recently started to learn Prolog and I had a question regarding making a predicate which gives u all the possible solutions (next moves) as the current spot is given. The best example is a maze. So this is my data which tells me 'w = white' and 'b = black' within a 5x5 maze:

```
grid([ [w, w, w, b, w],
    [b ,b, w, w, w],
    [w, w, w, b, w],
    [w, b, b, b, b],
    [w, w, w, w, w] ]).
```

I also implemented a predicated called white/1, which tells me if the given spot in the maze is white:

```
white(X/Y) :-
    grid(M),
    nth1(X, M, Line),
    nth1(Y, Line, w).
```

What I now want to do is make a predicate that gives me all the possible moves within the maze. For example if I query:

```
?- move(5/2, NextState).
NextState = 4/2 ;
NextState = 5/1 ;
NextState = 5/3 ;
No
```

This is my code, but it gives false and I know it's completely wrong, but I don't know how to implement such a predicate:

```
move(5/5, _).

move(X/Y, NextState) :-
    white(X/Y),
    X1 is X + 1,
    X1 =< 5,
    move(X1/Y, NextState),
    Y1 is Y + 1,
    Y1 =< 5,
    move(X/Y1, NextState),
    X2 is X - 1,
    X2 >= 5,
    move(X2/Y, NextState),
    Y2 is Y - 1,
    Y2 >= 0,
    move(X/Y2, NextState).
```

If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it! :)

**EDIT:**

```
move(X/Y, _) :-
    white(X/Y).

move(X/Y, X/Y) :-
    X1 is X + 1,
    move(X/Y, X1/Y);
    X2 is X - 1,
    move(X/Y, X2/Y);
    Y1 is Y + 1,
    move(X/Y, X/Y1);
    Y2 is Y - 1,
    move(X/Y, X/Y2).
```

If I query it gives me:

```
?- move(3/3, NextState).
true ;
NextState = 3/3 ;
NextState = 3/3 ;
NextState = 3/3 ;
NextState = 3/3 ;
```

Comment: You need disjunctions here. Learn how to use `;`.

Comment: @rajashekar `You need disjunctions here. Learn how to use ;` That reminds me of this joke. `A person is drowning 100 meters off the shore. The lifeguard throws them a line. The by stander notes that the line is only 51 meters long. The lifeguard says, I went more than half way.` While `;` is nice, without explaining it, it only gets the OP about half way. :( The other half could be cut `!`, conditional `->` or something more complicated.

Comment: @rajashekar I implemented the semicolon (;), and it gives me the 4 possible solutions, but wrong. I personally think that my base case isn't right.

Comment: What happens when you hit a wall?

Comment: Of interest: RosettaCode [Maze solving](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_solving#Prolog) - While not solving the maze problem the way you are, the code is of value.

Comment: @GuyCoder If it hits the wall it should look for other possible solutions. Thanks for sharing the Maze Solving link, but is seems more advanced than my code, haha. Also I don't have that much of experience yet. I was more interested if you could tell me how to improve the base case of mine, or the move/2 predicate in praticular.

Comment: @rajashekar Thanks, can't believe it was this simple, haha. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
move(X/Y, X1/Y1, Xm/Ym) :-
    X1 is X + 1, Y1 = Y, X1 =< Xm;
    X1 is X - 1, Y1 = Y, X1 > 0;
    X1 = X, Y1 is Y + 1, Y1 =< Ym;
    X1 = X, Y1 is Y - 1, Y1 > 0.
```

For each line in the above predicate we have a new direction. The `Xm/Ym` are bounds of the maze.

```
| ?- move(5/2, X, 5/5).

X = 4/2 ? ;

X = 5/3 ? ;

X = 5/1

yes
```

You can remove `Xm/Ym` as an argument and just put `5` in the body. Or you can define a new predicate

```
move1(Current, Next) :- move(Current, Next, 5/5)
```

Instead of disjunctions, we can also write multiple clauses.

```
move(X/Y, X1/Y) :- X1 is X + 1, X1 =< 5.
move(X/Y, X1/Y) :- X1 is X - 1, X1 > 0.
move(X/Y, X/Y1) :- Y1 is Y + 1, Y1 =< 5.
move(X/Y, X/Y1) :- Y1 is Y - 1, Y1 > 0.
```

Both are equivalent and this is even clearer.